# Error getting output from mysql.h using C++ and g++

Tags: c++, mysql, mariadb

I have a small piece of code which (should) allows me to connect to an MySQL database, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mariadb/mysql.h> // /usr/includes/mariadb/mysql.h

struct connection_details
{
    const char *server, *user, *password, *database;
};

MYSQL* mysql_connection_setup(struct connection_details mysql_details){
    MYSQL *connection = mysql_init(NULL); // mysql instance
    
    //connect database
    if(!mysql_real_connect(connection, mysql_details.server, mysql_details.user, mysql_details.password, mysql_details.database, 0, NULL, 0)){
        std::cout << "Connection Error: " << mysql_error(connection) << std::endl;
        exit(1); 
    }

    return connection;
}

// mysql_res = mysql result
MYSQL_RES* mysql_perform_query(MYSQL *connection, const char *sql_query){
    //send query to db
    if(mysql_query(connection, sql_query)){
        std::cout << "MySQL Query Error: " << mysql_error(connection) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return mysql_use_result(connection);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    MYSQL *con; // the connection
    MYSQL_RES *res; // the results
    MYSQL_ROW row;  // the results row (line by line)

    struct connection_details mysqlD;
    mysqlD.server = "localhost";  // where the mysql database is
    mysqlD.user = "netser";     // the root user of mysql   
    mysqlD.password = "root"; // the password of the root user in mysql
    mysqlD.database = "mydatabase"; // the databse to pick

    // connect to the mysql database
    con = mysql_connection_setup(mysqlD);

    // assign the results return to the MYSQL_RES pointer
    res = mysql_perform_query(con, "show tables");

    std::cout << ("MySQL Tables in mysql database:") << std::endl;
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=NULL)
        std::cout << row[0] << std::endl;

    /* clean up the database result set */
    mysql_free_result(res);
    /* clean up the database link */
    mysql_close(con);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it using:

```
g++ connectdb.cpp -o output && ./output
```

I get the next few errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDwpmw3.o: in function `mysql_connection_setup(connection_details)':
connectdb.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `mysql_init'
/usr/bin/ld: connectdb.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'
/usr/bin/ld: connectdb.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDwpmw3.o: in function `mysql_perform_query(st_mysql*, char const*)':
connectdb.cpp:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `mysql_query'
/usr/bin/ld: connectdb.cpp:(.text+0xef): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
/usr/bin/ld: connectdb.cpp:(.text+0x125): undefined reference to `mysql_use_result'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDwpmw3.o: in function `main':
connectdb.cpp:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row'
/usr/bin/ld: connectdb.cpp:(.text+0x213): undefined reference to `mysql_free_result'
/usr/bin/ld: connectdb.cpp:(.text+0x21f): undefined reference to `mysql_close'
```

{By the way, I use Parrot OS with Mariadb and use VSCode}

I have never worked with databases in C++ before, so I have barely any idea what could be the problem, but I can assure you that the database does exit and that the connection to mysql.h has no problems...

Comment: 1) You didn't link your application with `mysql` library, hence why linking failed. 2) For purposes of the demonstration, to reproduce the issue `g++ connectdb.cpp -o output` would have been enough, since no `output` was produced, due to the fact, that linking failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how I was executing it, I had to use

```
g++ connectdb.cpp -o output -L/usr/include/mariadb/mysql -lmariadbclient
```

And **not**

```
g++ connectdb.cpp -o output
```

For future people with the same problem, here's a breakdown:

**g++ connectdb.cpp -o output**  (normal compile)

**-L/usr/include/mariadb/mysql** (depending on what OS you have and if you use mariadb, you may have to change this to something like **-L/usr/include/mysql** instead, if you do use mariadb and still have a problem, remember to apt-get install libmariadb-dev)

**-lmariadbclient** (You have to apt-get install mariadb... If you're using MySQL, use **-lmysqlclient** instead)